# View/Controller Balance - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, controller

I have a query that adds a `Customer` to a certain `Category`. It is currently in the view template, and while it works, there's a bug - the customer is added to the category upon loading the page, *before* they have clicked the button.

I thought that moving that logic back to the controller might solve it (using `form_for`), then rendering the submit button in the view.

What do you think? And how would one implement it using `form_for`?

```
= link_to "JOIN CATEGORY NOW", root_path(@product.category.add_customer(current_customer)), class: "button4"
```

Edit:
Category Model

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
#Associations
belongs_to :product
has_many :customer_categories
has_many :customers, through: :customer_categories


def add_customer(customer_id)
 if customer = Customer.where(id: customer_id).first
    self.customers << customer unless self.customers.include?(customer)
end
end 
end
```

Product Model

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
include ActionView::Helpers
#Callbacks
after_create do 
    Category.create product: self
end
#Associations 
has_one :category, dependent: :destroy
```

Customer Model

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base

#Associations
has_many :customer_categories
has_many :categories, through: :customer_categories
```

EDIT #2:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `add_customer_category' for #<#<Class:0x007fcaebdbb5b0>:0x007fcae377ab90>):
```

routes:

```
resources :categories do
member do
  get 'add_customer', to: 'categories/add_customer'
end
end
```

Categories Controller:

```
def add_customer
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @product.category.add_customer(current_customer.id)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The customer is added to the category upon loading the page is happening because of this line:

```
= link_to "JOIN CATEGORY NOW", root_path(@product.category.add_customer(current_customer)), class: "button4"
```

Or more specifically this part of the code:

```
@product.category.add_customer(current_customer)
```

Since, when you load the page the Ruby code in view gets evaluated and hence the above code gets executed and customer gets added to the category.

Solution:

In your routes.rb:

```
resources :categories do
  member do
    get 'add_customer'
  end
end
```

Now, in your view:

```
= link_to "JOIN CATEGORY NOW", add_customer_category_path(@product.category)
```

In your `CategoriesController`:

```
def add_customer
  @category = Category.find(params[:id])
  if @category.add_customer(current_customer)
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    # Redirect user to an error page, maybe?
  end
end
```

Comment: Almost works! Button displays perfectly, but then when the customer joins the category and `http://localhost:3000/categories/3/add_customer` loads, I get `uninitialized constant AddCustomerController`.

Comment: @liroy : Could you post the error log from your rails server?

Comment: `Started GET "/categories/3/add_customer" for ::1 at 2015-12-02 05:02:42 -0800

ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant AddCustomerController):`

Comment: When I omit the `to: 'add_customer` in my routes and write only `resources :categories do
  member do
    get 'add_customer'
  end
end`, there's no routing error, but instead it now displays `undefined method 'add_customer' for nil:NilClass`, which is weird since this method is defined in the `Category` model.

Comment: @liroy : About your last comment, please follow step by step process O have posted. You don't need: `to: 'add_customer'` in routes. And `undefined method 'add_customer' for nil:NilClass` is happening because `@category` is `nil` please see why that is nill instead of a category object. Also, please post the error log from your rails server in the question instead of comment. It is hard to read and understand the log in comment.